# How to use Babel or webpack in a old php site with separate modules

Tags: javascript, php, webpack, babeljs, transpiler

I have an old project and I cannot use **ES6** syntax because I don't know how to implement Babel or Webpack to transpile **ES6** to **ES5**.

All the js modules are executed in a main.php file like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"  src="<?php echo $documentroot;?>
        MAIN.js?v=<?php echo $jsVersion;?>">
</script>
```

How can I configure Babel to work with this old setup? the website uses jQuery.
in the [Babel setup page](https://old.babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation) it assumes to use npm, but the project do not use node or npm, only pure php and jQuery.

Webpack also requires as prerequisite Node.js in the [installation guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/installation/#prerequisites)

Answer (score 2):

For practical use of Babel/Webpack, you do need the Node/npm stack available in your development environment.

The server actually serving your project does not need them available, if you package and transpile files locally (or in a CI pipeline) and deploy them onto the server, just like they were plain old JS modules.

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know another babel-like tool that I can use in my case?

Comment: You can use Babel just fine in your case. Just instead of shipping `MAIN.js` as-is, you transpile it beforehand.